# Finding differences and common in the 2 variable of the dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to find the differences between 2 cells of each row and extract the difference and common to the 2 new columns.

Here is an example of the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],'Tag1':["English,French",'Hindi,English','Kannada','French','German'],'Tag2':['Kannada','English,Hindi',                                                                                                'Kannada,Hindi','French,English','Kannada,German']})

ID  Tag1            Tag2
1   English,French  Kannada
2   Hindi,English   English,Hindi
3   Kannada         Kannada,Hindi
4   French          French,English
5   German          Kannada,German
```

I want to find all the new different languages added Tag2 by comparing from Tag1 as new Column "Difference" and All the common between the Tag1 and Tag2 to be added to new column as "Common"

The final output or result i need to get :

```
ID  Tag1            Tag2            Difference  Common
1   English,French  Kannada         Kannada     NaN
2   Hindi,English   English,Hindi   NaN         Hindi,English
3   Kannada         Kannada,Hindi   Hindi       Kannada
4   French          French,English  English     French
5   German          Kannada,German  Kannada     German
```

Note: This is just a small representation of data from the huge dataset I have, which is more than 300 000 rows and Column Tag1 & Tag2 with more than 5 languages.

I have tried doing almost everything which is available online from one week but couldn't  find a best way.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the set data structure to perform operations such as intersection, union and difference.

You can do some thing like following.

```
# A function which returns b - a, given a and b are arrays/lists
def diff(a,b):
    a = a.split(',') # split string by ','
    b = b.split(',')
    return ','.join(list(set(b) - set(a))) # find difference and then join the result by ','

# A function which returns common elements between a and b are arrays/lists
def common(a,b):
    a = a.split(',')
    b = b.split(',')
    return ','.join(list(set(b).intersection(set(a))))

# initialize your dataframe as you have provided in the question
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],'Tag1':["English,French",'Hindi,English','Kannada','French','German'],'Tag2':['Kannada','English,Hindi', 'Kannada,Hindi','French,English','Kannada,German']})

# add new columns for difference and common
df['common'] = [common(df['Tag1'][i],df['Tag2'][i]) for i in df.index]
df['diff'] = [diff(df['Tag1'][i],df['Tag2'][i]) for i in df.index]
```

The resultant df looks like below.

[image]

Hope this helps :),

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another version of usage `set` in Python. This should be much faster because it uses the vector operations.

```
df['set_Tag1'] = df['Tag1'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')).map(set)
df['set_Tag2'] = df['Tag2'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')).map(set)


df['diff'] = (df['set_Tag2'] - df['set_Tag1']).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df['common'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['set_Tag2'] & row['set_Tag1'], axis=1).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df.drop(columns=['set_Tag1', 'set_Tag2'], inplace=True)
```